# Is there any way to receive email inside my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, messageui

I want to get message from email body and to give an alert in my iPhone app. Is that possible?
Can i use the MessageUI.framework to RECEIVE email inside iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `MessageUI` to receive e-mail. You will have to create your own mail client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the MessageUI.framework.

For a prior project I created a simple PHP-based web service hosted on my web server. The web service interacted with the a POP sever. From the web service I could pull the needed information down to my app via stringWithContentsOfURL.

The POP account information was passed as encrypted parameters to the service.

PHP made it easy to parse out the interesting parts of the e-mails. Having the e-mail processing going on outside the app made it easy to fine-tune the sanitation of data in the e-mails.

Notifications could be handled locally - or on the server where your could automate running the PHP with a service like setcronjob.com

The script looked somewhat like this:

```
<?php

$msgList = array();

# Connect to POP server
if($conn = imap_open("{pop.yourserver.dk:110/pop3}INBOX","robot@yourserver.dk", "yourpassword")) {

    # Check for messages
    $check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($conn);

    # Process each message
    for($i = 1; $i <= $check->Nmsgs; $i++) {
        $message = imap_body($conn,$i);

        # If the message matches some criteria...
        preg_match('/([0-9\/]{8}) ([0-9:]{8}).*(Niros)[^\(]*\((.+)\)/m', $message, $matches);
        if($matches) {

            # ...save it
            array_push($msgList, $matches[1]);

        }

        # Delete all messages processed and spam
        imap_delete($connection,$message);
    }

    imap_close($conn);

}

# Print put the information pulled out of the matched emails
# JSON formatted data would be easy to parse
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo array_pop($msgList);
}

echo "Last update: ".date(DATE_RFC822);

?>
```